# Can anyone help me with this? I am not able to remove or re-install software center or any software

Tags: 14.04, software-center

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  libept1.4.12
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove it.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  software-center
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 17 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 3 015 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 204283 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing software-center (13.10-0ubuntu4.1) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/software-center.prerm: 6: /var/lib/dpkg/info/software-center.prerm: pyclean: not found
dpkg: error processing package software-center (--remove):
 subprocess installed pre-removal script returned error exit status 127
/var/lib/dpkg/info/software-center.postinst: 8: /var/lib/dpkg/info/software-center.postinst: pycompile: not found
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 127
Errors were encountered while processing:
 software-center
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Take a look at [this post](http://askubuntu.com/a/417125/62483). Let us know if this help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:-

```
sudo apt-get -m --reinstall install python python-minimal dh-python
sudo apt-get -f install
```

Then try your original installation/removal operation(s) again.

Comment: Glad to know that; you are welcome. :)
This means that one or more required python packages/files were missing from your system, which should not normally happen. Take care to ensure that necessary system packages don't get tampered with. :)

Comment: Just the second command was enough for my case.

Comment: i still get this error ```Errors were encountered while processing:
 alacarte
 kiki
 arandr
 python-rpi.gpio
 python-rainbowhat
 gyp
 spe
 python-cap1xxx
 python-automationhat
 python-phatbeat
 python-drumhat
 python-envirophat
 python-skywriter
 python-blinkt
 python-explorerhat
 python-pianohat
 python-motephat
 python-touchphat
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)```